# How to locate the git config file in Mac

Tags: git, macos

As title reads, how to locate the git config file in Mac? Not sure how to find it. Need to set

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Need some guidance on finding it..

Comment: There are actually multiple config files for git, they work in a hierarchy: `system`, `global`, `local`, `worktree` and `file`. Checkout this link from gitlab docs https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES

Answer (score 240, accepted):

The global Git configuration file is stored at `$HOME/.gitconfig` on all platforms.

However, you can simply open a terminal and execute `git config`, which will write the appropriate changes to this file.  You shouldn't need to manually tweak `.gitconfig`, unless you particularly want to.

Comment: can specify on how to find the folder on mac? need more help to find the file...

Comment: @lakesh Open a terminal and `echo $HOME`.

Comment: typed vim ~/.gitconfig

Comment: ~/.gitconfig will not exist unless you have some configuration.
<br />
    $ git config --global alias.s status
    $vim ~/.gitconfig
`

Comment: One more possible file path for global config: `~/.config/git/config`

Answer (score 244):

You don't need to find the file.

Only write this instruction on terminal:

```
git config --global --edit
```

Comment: this should really be the top answer. typing vim ~/.gitconfig wanted to create a new file when my gitconfig already existed

Comment: This worked for me since gitconfig file was not visible on Mac

Comment: @AskQ maybe you dont have any gitconfig. You can create a file .gitconfig on ~ or any other place in your development path

Comment: This is such a great answer, I used `git config --system --edit` to find the location of the system config which was in /usr/local/etc/gitconfig in my case. I had no Idea to look there. (opens the file in vim then `1` followed by `control + g` shows the path of the file)

Comment: In case anyone, such as me, can't make heads or tails of the terminal editor, you can use VS Code pointed at /Users/<account> and find .gitconfig in the Explorer window.

Comment: You can use `git config --global core.editor "your-editor"` command, as it says in the git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-C%3A-Git-Commands-Setup-and-Config).

After that `git config --global --edit` command will open `.gitconfig` file in your code editor.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to the problem is:

1. Find the **.gitconfig** file
2. [user]
       name = 1wQasdTeedFrsweXcs234saS56Scxs5423
       email = ankittanna@hotmail.com
   [credential]
       helper = osxkeychain
   [url ""]
       insteadOf = git://
   [url "https://"]
   [url "https://"]
       insteadOf = git://

there would be a blank **url=""**
replace it with **url="https://"**

```
[user]
    name = 1wQasdTeedFrsweXcs234saS56Scxs5423
    email = ankittanna@hotmail.com
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
[url "https://"]
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

This will work :)

Happy **Bower-ing**

Answer (score 3):

I use this function which is saved in .bash_profile and it works a treat for me.

```
function show_hidden () {
        { defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles $1; killall -HUP Finder; }
}
```

How to use:

```
show_hidden true|false
```

Comment: as an **alternative** you can also do this :** `alias showFiles='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app'`  AND  <br/>
`alias hideFiles='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app'`.  then to use simply type in console : `showFiles` or `hideFiles`

Comment: this works for me -> shift + ⌘ + .