# Cant Search for .gitconfig Even after AppleShowAllFiles

Tags: git, macos, osx-yosemite

I ran:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

And still I type in ".gitconfig" in finder and it doesn't find any of them and I have one in the root of my home folder for sure.

Comment: I think that is by design, spotlight just doesn't index them, and AFAIK Finder uses only spotlight for the search: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174805/does-spotlight-index-dotfiles-os-x-yosemite

Answer (score 0):

[The correct syntax for Yosemite is](http://landonbaine.com/2014/09/how-to-os-x-yosemite-show-hidden-files-and-folders/)

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true ; killall Finder
```

But to be honest, I would find it a pain in the rear end to see ALL the dot files (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.Trash`, etc.) appearing in my Finder windows.

The way I look for dot files most efficiently is via the Terminal command line.

Simply "`cd ~`" (to get to your home directory, or you can `cd` to wherever you keep all your source files) and then type in:

```
find . -name .gitconfig -print
```

On my own development machine, `.gitconfig` is in my home directory.  And I can easily open it into Xcode using "`open -a Xcode.app .gitconfig`".

More information can be seen [in this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283280/how-to-locate-the-git-config-file-in-mac).

Answer (score 0):

I also was doing a search in Finder for the `.gitconfig` file and it would turn up nothing. Even after using Terminal: `git config --list --show-origin` showed where the file existed.

To see it (and any hidden file) in Finder, click on the folder (that Terminal pointed to) in the left column of your Finder window, then use the following key command: `CMD-Shift-.` (period). You should then be able to see all the hidden files in that folder.
To hide the files, just enter the key command again.

Example to edit the `.gitconfig` file using TextEdit

1. In TextEdit, select `File > Open...`
2. Navigate to the folder where the file is
3. Enter the key command: `CMD-Shift-.` (period) to show the hidden files
4. Select `.gitconfig` to open it (it will appear faded in color)
5. Do with it as you would any file

I searched high and low and no where did I see any mention of the possibility of it being hidden from view. Hope this helps others.

Using OS X Sierra