# source tree shows loads of files changed when soapUI saves the project

Tags: xml, git, bitbucket, soapui, atlassian-sourcetree

I am working in the SoapUI(ReadyAPI 1.3.x) composite project hosted in bitbucket.

For the code management I use SourceTree.

When ever I pulled a new project and plug it in to soapUI, the first time the project gets saved, the source tree shows as allmost all the files chaged.

When I look at the file changes, I don't see a visible content change.

Ex: 
[1]
I have few image files in my test suite, the source tree shows the files are removed and added back to the same location (Basically they show as moved, obviously to the same location).

[2] xml test cases also shown as updated , but basically the content remains the same.

It looks like the soaUI changes the file binaries, and that changes is picked up by the source tree.

This is kind f annoying, I tried adding a .gitattributes the following config for every file type.

```
*.xml diff=tex
```

But no luck...

Does anyone have any clue ....?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure those difference are not end-of-line (eol) related (lf vs. cflf).

If they are, check if you have a config like `core.autocrlf` set to true.
If, so, set it to false, and clone your repo again, to see if the issue persists.

Once you have identified specific files which requires  eol management, list them in a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), with [`core.eol` directives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/6309).

Note: I don't know about '`tex`' as a valid config value.

```
*.atype -text
```

That would prevent `.atype` files from being normalized regardless of their content.

Comment: Hi @VonC, Thanks for the reply. I tried `git config --global core.autocrlf input` in my mac. And `*.xml  -text` in .gitattribute. Also tried `*.xml   text eol=crlf` in .gitattribute.  But none of seems to  be helpful.  I did nit do a clone , but I did a hard reset. Any Idea ..... ?

Comment: Try at least a `git config --global core.autocrlf false`, followed by a new clone of the repo, and checked if the issue persists with the new cloned repo.

Comment: I tried that. It reduced the number of changes a bit (from 1840 to 1680). But no luck. BTW when we do `git config --global core.autocrlf false` in mac, where does (which file) it recorded ?

Comment: @Asanke it is in the global config: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16283280/6309 and https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/235494/storage-location-for-global-gitconfig

Comment: Thanks @VonC, Yup, It's there. But didn't resolve my issue. Let me post this in a Smartbear forum, to check if some change from the SpoaUI side could prevent these.