# how to move a local git repository from a pc to a Mac without losing history

Tags: git, macos, repository

I have been working on a repository on my pc for a couple of weeks and I have 11 commits on it. now, I just got a MacBook and I want to move my working environment there. How do I move my repositories there without losing the history of the repo. Do I just copy and paste the folders using an external drive and continue working there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The information of a git repository are stored in the (invisible) sub-folder `.git`.

If you move the entire repository folder then all your repository's history should be preserved.

The only thing not saved in that folder are system/user-wide configuration, e.g. your user.name and user.email - if you also want to transfer your configuration, have a look at [How to locate the git config file in Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283280/how-to-locate-the-git-config-file-in-mac)